# AndroidStudio E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf3d96ad0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem with my android app. I make a popwindow containing timepicker, it makes error when running on android 6.0.

The error:

> E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xf3d96ad0.

Answer (score 1):

There is bug in `MarshMallow 6.0` and it can be fix in `MarshMallow 6.0.1` so Change your device Version to `6.0.1` and then check it. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Hello. My application has this kind of error too. Yes this error fix in Android 6.0.1 but someone want to use my application and his phone will be android 6.0.1, What can do